# Starting delayed Tasks

Tags: c#, task, delay

During WCF events called by web clients my WCF Server needs to Start a new asynchronous Task on each call but with a delay of more then a minute.

My current solution consists on `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoTask());` where  `DoTask()` calls `await Task.Delay(XXX);` before executing its code. This WCF event happens allot in our production environment which causes a creation of many threads that remain stuck for a whole minute.

One of the solutions I have thought of was to use `Task.Delay(XXX).ContinueWith((i) => DoTask());`  In this solution no threads are created until DoTask() begins to run but I see 2 task that are created for `Task.Delay()` call.

Which solution is better (or maybe neither...) Creating many threads or creating many Tasks?
Thanks.

Comment: 'better' In which concept? performance? resource consumption? ...

Comment: WCF? Are you doing *very slow* responses or you trying to do background execution? Different unrelated solutions depending on what you want... or if you actually mean WCF...

Comment: "which causes a creation of many threads that remain stuck for a whole minute" - it shouldn't. How are you observing that? It may cause several threads to be started within the thread-pool, but I wouldn't expect any to be "stuck". (It's not clear why you're calling StartNew rather than just executing the async method, admittedly.)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Scheduling Frameworks have the ability to schedule delayed jobs. e.g. [Hangfire](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html) (not affiliated)

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @JonSkeet I have created a dump file from production and I opened and debugged it on my dev machine . then I saw about 800 threads of the DoTask()

Comment: @ShayLin: It's hard to help with only that small amount of information. If the duplicate doesn't already help you, please edit the post to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> This event happens allot in our production environment which causes a creation of many threads that remain stuck for a whole minute.

It should not. It will take a thread pool thread to start `DoTask()`, but when it reaches `await Task.Delay(XXX);` it should release the thread back to the pool. You will have great deal of tasks, but that is usually not a problem. That is the point of `await`, that it releases the used thread to do whatever, while allowing it, or another thread, to resume execution at a later time.

> One of the solutions I have thought of was to use Task.Delay(XXX).ContinueWith((i) => DoTask()); In this solution no threads are created until DoTask() begins to run but I see 2 task that are created for Task.Delay() call.

If you run this on the main thread the `ContinueWith` should use the `TaskScheduler.Current` and thus run `DoTask` on the main thread. You could change this to `TaskScheduler.Default` to run in on the threadpool instead. If it is ok to run `DoTAsk` on the main thread then you could just use `await`.

> Which solution is better (or maybe neither...) Creating many threads or creating many Tasks? Thanks.

Creating many tasks is better. A thread requires a stack and other overhead. The main purpose of tasks is to reduce the need for this overhead.